# iOS 7 Single App Mode Change Device Settings

Tags: ios

I have a an iOS7 app running in a **Single App Mode** on an iPad.
The device is put in the Single App Mode via Apple Configurator.

The Single App mode does not respond to the Home Button.

Is there a way a user can access the device settings when running in a Single App Mode (For example change device brightness or turn bluetooth ON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

A device running in single app mode will not allow the user to exit the app to access settings.

A possible solution is to use the [Restrictions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13) configuration payload with the `autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs` key set to the bundle id for your app.

You will need to install a configuration profile either manually or through an MDM with this payload on the device.

Once the profile is installed your app you can enter single app mode programmatically by calling [UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession).

You can now add some UI (like a button) to permit the user to exit guided access and launch settings, you exit guided access using the same API to enter it.

**Note:** This won't force the user back to your app once they have exited your app. You will have to find some other way to do that (ugly hack: force install another configuration profile that brings your app back into single app mode, once that has happened, remove this profile but leave the one permitting it to request guided access).